# How can I open a wallet in multibit, after clicking "close wallet"?

Tags: multibit

I accidentally clicked on *close wallet* and now I do not know how to open it. I don't even know where it's saved. When I click on multibit.exe it shows nothing. No wallet. Please advise what to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the multibit.org help page there is a support page specifically for ['lost wallets'](https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_support_missingWallets.html).

It tells you the directory where the default wallet is stored. (This is operating system specific)